# How to stop redirection to index.php main file in code igniter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website domain.com which is based in code igniter. When someone enters a wrong url it redirects it to https://domain.com/index.php

I want to redirect redirect it https://domain.com and do not want index.php to be present in the urls. I have tried everything in htaccess file but it dooesnt work.

Here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55  .php55 .php


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand rightly, you want to redirect index.php to the root?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know if not

Comment: After adding this, if I go to domain.com/any-wrong-url , it displays message page not found. This is not really what I want to do. I want to redirect that to domain.com